# Webpack: Node Modules Not Found

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, node-modules, webpack-config

I have been working with webpack today, and all of a sudden it starts throwing me errors that it can't resolve common node modules like `fs` and `inspect`. I found [this github issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447) that gives a workaround by setting the modules to none through webpack's config. After doing that, I got this error in my browser:
[image: Browser Error]

I believe that this pertains to the fact that in the workaround the modules were replaced by empty placeholders. I have already tried re-installing all of the modules. Hopefully somebody can help with this!

Comment: Where are you trying to run this webpack code?  In nodejs or in the browser?  You cannot use the `fs` module in Javascript code that runs in the browser.  The `fs` module only runs within nodejs.  The same is true for the `net` module, the `http` module and others.

Comment: I am not using the `fs` module in any of my client-side code. Webpack was working fine before and then all of a sudden in a production build it did this. This is not a problem with my code, and is probably a problem with probably either npm or webpack.

Comment: Are you 200% sure that you're not using some module that itself uses the `fs` module?  Something is apparently attempting to load the `fs` module.

Comment: Yes I am 200% sure that I am not using any node modules that should do that, and that I am not using the module itself. Again, It worked before for development builds but stopped working after trying to do a production build, with nothing changed in the code.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

fix the problem by changing webpack.config.js:

```
var config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
config.node = { fs: 'empty' };
module.exports = config;
```

Comment: I already tried this. It just led to errors in the browser (see screenshot above)